# Custom fiscal quarters in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with panel data where I have several public companies and several quarterly observations for each company. I was thinking that the best way to organize the data would be a MultiIndex where the first level is a unique company identifier (in this case 'gvkey') and the second level is the quarter.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this as fiscal year ends can be any month of the year, which presents me from using `DatetimeIndex.quarter`. Is there a way for me to define custom quarters in Pandas that are meaningful to Pandas? I could simply use a string such as '2014Q1', but I was hoping to be able to have it be some sort of object so that Pandas would know what is the prior quarter or know that the fiscal year end for that company is month 10, so 2014Q1 would end in January 2014. Is this possible?

Here's an example of some data I have in a DataFrame. The index is `gvkey`, a unique company identifier. `datadate` is the last day of the quarter (i.e., the last day of the last month of the quarter), `datafqtr` is the year and quarter as a string, and `fyr` is the month of the fiscal year-end (e.g., 5 means the year ends in May).

```
        conm    datadate    datafqtr    fyr
gvkey               
001004  AAR CORP    2014-02-28  2013Q3  5.0
001004  AAR CORP    2014-05-31  2013Q4  5.0
001004  AAR CORP    2014-08-31  2014Q1  5.0
001004  AAR CORP    2014-11-30  2014Q2  5.0
001045  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC 2014-03-31  2014Q1  12.0
001045  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC 2014-06-30  2014Q2  12.0
001045  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC 2014-09-30  2014Q3  12.0
001045  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC 2014-12-31  2014Q4  12.0
001050  CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP 2014-03-31  2014Q1  12.0
001050  CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP 2014-06-30  2014Q2  12.0
001050  CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP 2014-09-30  2014Q3  12.0
001050  CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP 2014-12-31  2014Q4  12.0
001062  ASA GOLD AND PRECIOUS METALS    2014-02-28  2014Q1  11.0
001062  ASA GOLD AND PRECIOUS METALS    2014-05-31  2014Q2  11.0
001062  ASA GOLD AND PRECIOUS METALS    2014-08-31  2014Q3  11.0
001062  ASA GOLD AND PRECIOUS METALS    2014-11-30  2014Q4  11.0
001072  AVX CORP    2014-03-31  2013Q4  3.0
001072  AVX CORP    2014-06-30  2014Q1  3.0
001072  AVX CORP    2014-09-30  2014Q2  3.0
001072  AVX CORP    2014-12-31  2014Q3  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

After some head scratching I think I know what you are asking for.

First, I'll make some data:

```
# Make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'gvkey' : ['001004']*4 +\
                             ['001045']*4 +\
                             ['001050']*4 +\
                             ['001062']*4 +\
                             ['001072']*4,
                   'conm' : ['AAR CORP']*4 +\
                            ['AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC']*4 +\
                            ['CECO ENVIRONMENTAL CORP']*4 +\
                            ['ASA GOLD AND PRECIOUS METALS']*4 +\
                            ['AVX CORP']*4,
                   'datadate' : ['2014-02-28', '2014-05-31', '2014-08-31', '2014-11-30'] +\
                                ['2014-03-31', '2014-06-30', '2014-09-30', '2014-12-31']*2 +\
                                ['2014-02-28', '2014-05-31', '2014-08-31', '2014-11-30'] +\
                                ['2014-03-31', '2014-06-30', '2014-09-30', '2014-12-31'],
                   'datafqtr' : ['2013Q3', '2013Q4', '2014Q1', '2014Q2'] +\
                               ['2014Q1', '2014Q2', '2014Q3', '2014Q4']*3 +\
                               ['2013Q4', '2014Q1', '2014Q2', '2014Q3'],
                   'fyr' : [5]*4 +\
                           [12]*8 +\
                           [11]*4 +\
                           [3]*4})

# Reorder columns
df = df[[df.columns[-1]] + list(df.columns[:-1])]

# Convert 'datadate' to datetime
df.loc[:, 'datadate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'datadate'])

# Show the dataframe
df
```

[image: original df]

Second, (based on what I interpreted the problem to be) I will create a replicate of your datafqtr column. To do this I used a modulo 12 mapping technique for creating the quarters and years:

```
# Copy the dataframe
df1 = df.copy()

# Insert 'year' column
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'year',
           df1.loc[:, 'datadate'].dt.year)

# Insert 'month' column
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'month',
           df1.loc[:, 'datadate'].dt.month)

# Subtract 'fyr' from 'month'
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'month-fyr',
           df1.loc[:, 'month'] - df1.loc[:, 'fyr'])

# Create 'new_year' column
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'new_year',
           np.where((df1.loc[:, 'month-fyr'] <= 0) & (df1.loc[:, 'fyr'] < 6),
                    df1.loc[:, 'year'] - 1,
                    df1.loc[:, 'year']))

# Make a mapper for mapping the values of 'month-fyr' to 'new_qtr'
mapper = {-9 : 1,
          -6 : 2,
          -3 : 3,
          0 : 4,
          3 : 1,
          6 : 2,
          9 : 3}

# Insert the 'new_qtr' column
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'new_qtr',
           df1.loc[:, 'month-fyr'].map(mapper))

# Insert 'new_datafqtr' column (this should be equivalent to 'datafqtr')
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'new_datafqtr',
           df1.loc[:, 'new_year'].astype(str) + 'Q' + df1.loc[:, 'new_qtr'].astype(str))

# Show the dataframe
df1
```

[image: new df]

Note that when I created the `'new_year'` column I had to consider whether or not `'fyr'` was < than 6. This is important in creating the column.

If you want to `groupby 'gvkey', 'conm', 'new_year', 'new_qtr'` this will show the correct fiscal years and quarters (in order) for each.

Hope this helps!

## Edit:

```
# Insert random revenue
df1.insert(df1.shape[1],
           'random_revenue',
           np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 1000000, size = df1.shape[0]))

# Groupby 'gvkey', 'conm', 'new_year', 'new_qtr' and sum 'random_revenue'
df_group = df1.groupby(['gvkey',
                        'conm',
                        'new_year',
                        'new_qtr']).agg({'random_revenue' : 'sum'})

# Find difference in revenue for "AAR CORP" between 2013Q3 and 2014Q2
df_group.loc[('001004', 'AAR CORP', slice(None), [3, 2])].diff()
```

Documentation for pd.diff() --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas-dataframe-diff

Comment: Ian, this is awesome. Definitely learned some things about Pandas and NumPy from following this. I probably wasn't as clear as I should have been in my question. My data source always provides the `datafqtr` column, so I don't need to recreate it. What I was hoping was that Pandas would have an object for dealing with quarters so that I could something like an intelligent shift and grab a value from a prior quarter.

For example, maybe I want to calculate revenue change from the prior quarter. I could just tell Pandas that my time period is quarter, and I want the -1 Q. I'm guessing I can't?